# Duplicated Question in order theory

Tags: order-theory

(Duplicate) I'm solving some questions in discrete mathematics, and I stuck with this problem. 
Prove that there are uncountably many non-isomorphic linear orderings in N.

Comment: @mrp That was me, but the answer used ordering theory which I cannot understand. The hint seems simple

Comment: @user220927: The hint is the more complicated idea that I rejected when I wrote up my answer. I can add it mine if you really want — let me know either way — but the underlying idea is very similar to that of the one that I gave.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Hmm.. No wonder the book gave these kinds of problems without any preliminaries.. Can you give some solution using the hint?

Comment: @user220927: I’ll add it to the earlier answer. It’ll take me a few minutes to write it up again.

Comment: Okay, I’ve added that version to my answer to the other question. And this really *is* a duplicate.